# Display random pictures with timer delay

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I am making an application that randomly selects a picture from a preset group of pictures and displays it to a image view.  This should happen every second or so until it has gone through 20 cycles.

Hear is my header and implementation code:

```
@interface spinController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageHolder;
NSTimer *MovementTimer;    
}
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender;
-(void)displayPic;
@end


@implementation spinController
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender
{
int count = 0;
while (count <20)
{
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self    selector:@selector(displayPic) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    count++;
}
}
-(void)displayPic
{
int r = arc4random() % 2;
if(r==0)
{
imageHolder.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puppy1.jpg"];
}
else
{
imageHolder.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puppy2.jpg"];
}
}   
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}  
@end
```

I have made this application in a much more advanced form in WPF and ran into similar issues where the pictures do no cycle through properly.  If I hit spin it randomizes but does not go through the 20 cycles... just one.  This is my first application in objective-c and realize the efficiency of the method I choose will determine how good my application will run in a more complex form.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use NSTimer with this simple while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728570/how-can-i-use-nstimer-with-this-simple-while-loop) See also [While loop using NSTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18678715) and [A NSTimer in while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7468335)

Comment: Is each image named, "puppy1," "puppy2," "puppy3," etc?

Comment: yes, I have two in use.  puppy1 and puppy2

Comment: Oh, I see.  Writing an answer now...

Comment: thank you.  There are so many inefficient timer methods while this is such a common and seemingly simple task to perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling the timer repeatedly within the while loop; and since that particular while loop will complete within a millisecond or so, you're creating 20 timers one after another in immediate succession.  Because of this, only the final image will show up in the `imageHolder` view.  Edit:  Even if the loop were to take more than a millisecond per iteration, I believe the NSTimer wouldn't actually fire until the method exits anyway.

In order to show the images one after another as you're trying to do, (1) use the `NSTimer` without the while loop, (2) keep track of the iterations using a `count` *class* instance variable so as not to lose the value of the variable upon the completion of the various methods, and (3) pass along the `NSTimer` to the `displayPic` method so you can invalidate the timer from there upon the 20th iteration.  For example:

```
// Declare the "count" instance variable.
int count;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
} 

-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender {
    // The count starts at 0, so initialize "count" to 0.
    count = 0;

    // Use an NSTimer to call displayPic: repeatedly every 1 second ("repeats" is set to "YES")
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(displayPic:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

// Pass along the NSTimer to the displayPic method so that it can be invalidated within this method upon the 20th iteration
-(void)displayPic:(NSTimer *)timer {

    // Get the random number
    int r = arc4random() % 2;

    // If the number is 0, display puppy1.jpg, else display puppy2.jpg.
    if(r == 0) {
        imageHolder.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puppy1.jpg"];
    }
    else {
        imageHolder.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puppy2.jpg"];
    }

    // Increment "count" to reflect the number of times the NSTimer has called this method since the button press
    count ++;

    // If the count == 20, stop the timer.
    if (count == 20)
        [timer invalidate];
}   

@end
```

Comment: This makes so much sense.  I was under the impression that pause would pause the main thread.  This also cleared up another issue I was having with the count instance variable in the display pic method.

Answer (score 0):

Change repeats to `YES`. This causes the timer to run again and again. Then instead of a while loop check the count in the method itself.